# Returning error from custom lambda custom middleware

Tags: node.js, lambda, middy

for the last 3-4 hours i've been trying to correctly return error from custom @middy middleware unsuccessfully

```
export const middyfy = (handler: any) => {
    return middy(handler).use(middyJsonBodyParser());
};

export const authorizedMiddify = (handler: any) => {
  return middyfy(handler)
    .use(httpHeaderNormalizer())
    .use(httpErrorHandler())
    .use({
      before: (request, next) => {
          console.log(3)
          throw createError(401, 'Unauthorized');
      }
    });
};
```

this logs:

```
{
  body: 'Unauthorized',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
  statusCode: 401
}
```

and in postman i receive empty body and 502 error.

what is wrong here?
P.S: createError is from @middy/util

Answer (score 0):

I  think you're looking for `createHttpError` from `@middy/http-error-handler`. Alternatively, you can create a wrapper for this—maybe call it `createError()`—and throw.
[documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@middy/http-error-handler)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: might be wrong middy package.

I have encountered the same error as you. Although I don't know the exact package that you used.

I fixed mine by using [@middy/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@middy/core) instead of just [middy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/middy). It is not noticeable in plain JS, but in Typescript there is a type error for the `middy(handler).use(httpErrorHandler())`, this might be the reason why it is throwing a 502 error because httpErrorHandler is an incompatible middleware.

Type Error:

```
Argument of type 'MiddlewareObj<any, any, Error, Context>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MiddlewareObject<APIGatewayProxyEvent, ResponsePayload, Context>'.Types of property 'before' are incompatible.
```